# What is the best way to mutate remote data fetched with useQuery

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I am fairly new to graphQL and Apollo. I hope I can make myself clear:

I am fetching data using the apollo/react-hook `useQuery`. Afterwards I populate a form with the data so the client can change it. When he is done, the data gets send back to the server using `useMutation`.

Until now, I use `onCompleted` to store the fetched data in the component state. That looks like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core'; 
const Index = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(null)
    const {data, loading, error} = useQuery<typeof queryType>(query, {
        onCompleted: data => {
            // modify data slightly
            setState(data)
        }
    })

    return (
        <TextField value={state} onChange={() => setState(event.target.value)}/>
    )
}
```

The form than uses the values stored in the component state and the form handlers use `setState`
to change it.

My question now is, if this is the best practice and if the storing of the fetched data in a local component state neccessary.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. It is necessary since at first `state` is null. If you don't `setState` you can't update the view, thus your form woudln't be updated.

Comment: I definetly need a local state or does working with apollos local states also trigger rerenders? In the real application I have a few dropdown menus.

Comment: Sorry i am not familiar with apollos. But since you said that apollos already has a state for the same data, you shouldn't create your own state. You should only have one state for a set of data. If apollos handles the state, then good for you!

Comment: Well I said it with a big question mark. I dont think it acts like a functional component state(?).

Comment: The `data` property exposed by Apollo is global state that represents remote data. While there's way to mutate it, it makes no sense to do so in the context of a user form. Even if it's initialized based on some other state, a form's state only represents the user's input. If we were only rendering the data, then using component state would be superfluous. But that's not the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't want to just fetch and render the data -- you want to be able to mutate it when the form values change -- we can't just utilize the `data` as is. Unless you're using [uncontrolled inputs](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) and refs to manage your forms (which you probably [shouldn't do](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs)), then you're going to need to use some component state.

I think your current approach is mostly fine. The biggest downside is that if the query takes a while (maybe the user has a spotty internet connection), there's a window for them to start filling out the form only to have their input overridden once the query completes. You'd have to explicitly disable the inputs or hide the form until loading completes in order to prevent this scenario.

An alternative approach is to split your component into two:

```
const Outer = () => {
  const {data, loading, error} = useQuery(query)

  if (!data) {
    return null // or a loading indicator, etc.
  }

  return <Inner data={data}/>
}

const Inner = ({ data }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(data.someField)

  <TextField value={value} onChange={() => setValue(event.target.value)}/>
}
```

By not rendering of the inner component until loading is complete, we ensure that the initial props we pass to it have the data from the query. We can then use those props to initialize our state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my real application I already take care of that with a loading component.

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer The loading component is really beside the point of the post. The key is that you're taking advantage of how state is initialized. The above would not be possible with a single component (without also using `useEffect`) because only the first set of props is used to initialize the state.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `useQuery` only has a state for `responseId`: https://github.com/trojanowski/react-apollo-hooks/blob/master/src/useQuery.ts

But you get a `refetch` function from the `useQuery` as well.

```
 const { loading, error, data, refetch } = useQuery(...);
```

Try calling `refetch()`, after you used `useMutation()` to update the data. It shouldn't trigger a rerender. You probably have to set your own state for that reason.
Maybe something like:

```
const handleUpdate = () =>{
   setData(refetch());
}
```

Alternativly you get the data after using `useMutation` which is also in the state: https://github.com/trojanowski/react-apollo-hooks/blob/master/src/useMutation.ts

```
  const [update, { data }] = useMutation(UPDATE_DATA);
```

`data` will always be the newest value so you could also do:

```
useEffect(()=>{
 setData(data);
 // OR
 // setData(refetch());
}, [data])
```